# Looking for a more "pythonic" solution for my practice task

Tags: python, string, list, function, split

everyone. While practicing strings I encountered a practice task that made me struggle with making my code look as simple as it can be.

The body of the task:

> Write a function that transposes a list of strings, in which each string contains
> multiple words separated by whitespace. Specifically, it should perform in such a
> way that if you were to pass the list ['abc def ghi', 'jkl mno pqr', 'stu vwx yz']
> to the function, it would return ['abc jkl stu', 'def mno vwx', 'ghi pqr yz'] .

My code:

```
old_list = ['abc def ghi', 'jkl mno pqr', 'stu vwx yz']
    
    def func(old_list):
        new_list = []
        sentence = ''.join(old_list)
        index_one = sentence[0:3] + ' ' + sentence[11:14] + ' ' + sentence[22:25]
        index_two = sentence[4:7] + ' ' + sentence[15:18] + ' ' + sentence[26:29]
        index_three = sentence[8:11] + ' ' + sentence[19:22] + ' ' + sentence[30:32]
        new_list.append(index_one)
        new_list.append(index_two)
        new_list.append(index_three)
        return new_list
```

it looks so "not good" even I can see that. How can I optimize it so it would look cleaner?

Comment: Use `str.split()` and `zip()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break the problem into two parts:

1. how do we transform a string to a list
2. how do we slice and dice the lists to get your output

#1

Let's say we have the following strings, similar to yours.

```
>>> s1 = '1 2 3'
>>> s2 = '4 5 6'
>>> s3 = '7 8 9'
```

You can use `.split()` to split the text into a list by a delimiter (by default `' '`)

```
>>> s1.split()
['1', '2', '3']
```

Let's do that for all our strings:

```
lists = [x.split() for x in [s1, s2, s3]]
>>> lists
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

#2

How do we get the first element from all the lists, then the second, and so on?

We use `zip`: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

```
>>> list(zip(*lists))
[('1', '4', '7'), ('2', '5', '8'), ('3', '6', '9')]
```

If your program wants you to display those as strings, and not a list of tuples:

```
>>> [" ".join(x) for x in zip(*lists)]
['1 4 7', '2 5 8', '3 6 9']
```

Comment: You forgot to add the join step to make them back into sentences

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code which utilizes the split method, and then loops through each list to concatenate the nth same element number of each list:

```
L = ['abc def ghi', 'jkl mno pqr', 'stu vwx yz']

def custom_L(L):
    #Assigning the Final List before looping
    Final = []
    #Splitting each string in the List
    for i in range(len(L)):
        L[i] = L[i].split()
    '''This basically says hey in i = 1 for example
     I want you to concatenate each first element 
     for each list inside L with ' ' in between as a seperator
     and the same for second and same for third'''
    for i in range(len(L)):
        Final += [' '.join([SubL[i] for SubL in L])]
    return Final


output = custom_L(L)
print(output)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make use of the split method of string objects for splitting the strings and than use numpy to transpose it

```
import numpy as np
old_list = ['abc def ghi', 'jkl mno pqr', 'stu vwx yz']

app = np.array([_.split(' ') for _ in old_list])

print(app.T)


# [['abc' 'jkl' 'stu']
#  ['def' 'mno' 'vwx']
#  ['ghi' 'pqr' 'yz']]
```

EDIT: for all the commenteres disparaging numpy and saying this can be done in one line (I think for a beginner this is much more difficult to look at)

```
print([' '.join(_) for _ in zip(*[_.split(' ') for _ in old_list])])
# ['abc jkl stu', 'def mno vwx', 'ghi pqr yz']
```

Comment: really? numpy, for this?

Comment: Why not? I find easy and it make the code look clean

Comment: Because this can be solved in a single line using the std lib without the HUGE overhead of installing `numpy` just for this tiny mundane task.

Comment: The request was to make it look clean. Nothing was said about using extra packages.

Comment: I don't see anything egregious with this answer and while it might be "overkill" if viewed in isolation, if one regularly used it then it seems perfectly fine. I would say, for a complete novice looking for help on an assignment, it might not be in the spirit of teaching the student how to "program".

Comment: Even though it's overkill, I think it's an interesting approach to the problem. Certainly beats something like `list(map(lambda x:' '.join(x), zip(*map(lambda x:x.split(), old_list)))` in terms of readability.

Comment: Yeah I added a similar version which I also think is hard to read for a beginner. The nice think about python is all the packages that makes your life easy. If i wanted to reinvent the wheel everytime i'd be writing in aseembly

Comment: *"I think for a beginner this is much more difficult to look at"* because all you actually need is `list(zip(*[s.split() for s in old_list]))` (or even just `list(zip(*map(str.split, old_list)))`). Now all is left is to join the inner tuples to  strings

Comment: @DeepSpace is correct. Besides it being a one-liner, that is exactly what my answer suggests.